# Behat 3 AfterScenario not running

Tags: php, behat

I have an issue with Behat 3, AfterScenario hook.

It does not seem to run.

Test code:

```
    /**
    * @afterScenario @database 
    */    
    public function deleteAccountDbs()
    {
        Log::debug('deleteAccountDbs');
    }
```

Is there something I might be missing?

AfterFeature and AfterSuite hooks are running fine.

Comment: It should be `@AfterScenario`, with a capital 'A'. Not sure if that's the issue though.

Comment: No it's not, the case plays no role.

Answer (score 0):

Was fast on the previous answer with `static`. That only concerns suites, not scenarios. I just tried the following, and it works fine.

```
/**
 * @afterScenario @database
 *
 * @param AfterScenarioScope $scope
 */
public function afterScenario(AfterScenarioScope $scope)
{
    print('hooked');
}
```

The only apparent reason why it might not work for you is you don't have the `@database` tag on your feature / scenario.

Comment: I dont know why, but I got it to work after also adding a beforeScenario function.